# Buildozer and cython conflict

Tags: python, cython, buildozer

I am trying to build an android APK using buildozer. I have the following versions of python, Cython and buildozer:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 03:52:42) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Cython
>>> Cython.__version__
'0.29.13'

Buildozer 0.39
```

But when I try to build my APK I encounter the following error

```
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__pyx_f_5jnius_5jnius_create_proxy_instance':
jnius/jnius.c:34306:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_PY_LONG_LONG(((PY_LONG_LONG)((void *)__pyx_v_py_obj))); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[1]; __pyx_lineno = 170; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                              ^
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_ExceptionSave':
jnius/jnius.c:51615:19: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_type'
     *type = tstate->exc_type;
                   ^
jnius/jnius.c:51616:20: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_value'
     *value = tstate->exc_value;
                    ^
jnius/jnius.c:51617:17: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_traceback'
     *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                 ^
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_ExceptionReset':
jnius/jnius.c:51629:22: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_type'
     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                      ^
jnius/jnius.c:51630:23: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_value'
     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                       ^
jnius/jnius.c:51631:20: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_traceback'
     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                    ^
jnius/jnius.c:51632:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_type'
     tstate->exc_type = type;
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:51633:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_value'
     tstate->exc_value = value;
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:51634:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_traceback'
     tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
           ^
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_GetException':
jnius/jnius.c:51821:22: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_type'
     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                      ^
jnius/jnius.c:51822:23: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_value'
     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                       ^
jnius/jnius.c:51823:20: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_traceback'
     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                    ^
jnius/jnius.c:51824:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_type'
     tstate->exc_type = local_type;
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:51825:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_value'
     tstate->exc_value = local_value;
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:51826:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_traceback'
     tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
           ^
jnius/jnius.c: In function '__Pyx_ExceptionSwap':
jnius/jnius.c:51848:22: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_type'
     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                      ^
jnius/jnius.c:51849:23: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_value'
     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                       ^
jnius/jnius.c:51850:20: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_traceback'
     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                    ^
jnius/jnius.c:51851:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_type'
     tstate->exc_type = *type;
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:51852:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_value'
     tstate->exc_value = *value;
           ^
jnius/jnius.c:51853:11: error: 'PyThreadState' has no member named 'exc_traceback'
     tstate->exc_traceback = *tb;
           ^
```

Can someone please help me to find what the problem might be?

[Added later]

This looks like the command that has failed

```
building 'jnius' extension
/usr/bin/ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -fomit-frame-pointer -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -mandroid -isystem <my_home>.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -I<my_home>.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isysroot <my_home>.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/sysroot -I<my_home>projects/bfg/bfg_kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/bfgApp/include/python3.7 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DANDROID -fomit-frame-pointer -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -mandroid -isystem <my_home>.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -I<my_home>.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isysroot <my_home>.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/sysroot -I<my_home>projects/bfg/bfg_kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/bfgApp/include/python3.7 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -I<my_home>projects/bfg/bfg_kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -fPIC -I<my_home>projects/bfg/bfg_kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I<my_home>projects/bfg/bfg_kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/jnius/jnius.o
```

[Update 28 Aug 2019]
I have managed to build the APK on another computer. On the 2nd computer, the directory

```
.../.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/android-python3-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21
```

contains a folder 'jnius' which contains jnius.c. I have copied that to the main computer, but the build fails with the same message.

The jnius.c file was built with the same version of Cython as the version on the main computer.

If I delete the file jnius.c, the build fails with the same message

Comment: Right at the top of your C file there should be a line "Generated by Cython xxxx" - what doest that say? The reason I ask is that I think this was fixed in Cython a year or two ago, but it's possible that your files were generated by an old version.

Comment: @DavidW I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by my 'C file'

Comment: jnius/jnius.c - the file that the errors are coming from

Comment: @DavidW I've searched for jnius.c and cannot find it. Where should it be?

Comment: To be honest I don't know since I don't really know anything about the android build system. It is possible that it's only created temporarily then deleted by the build system (in which case my hunch is wrong). I suspect that isn't the case though.

Comment: @DavidW I think you're right. I have seen references to similar problems on various forums. I think I have and 'old' version of something lurking around, but what? That's why I put version numbers i my question. I think I've got the latest of all of those

Comment: To try to explain a bit better: Cython is a two step process. Cython converts a py/pyx to c file. The c file is compiled to a shared library. You can do the second step without having Cython installed. My guess is that the c file has already been generated (sometime in the past) and isn't being updated. The version of Cython you have doesn't matter if it isn't being used! You therefore want to find the C file and delete it/regenerate it. On some systems it might be enough to save a change to the py/pyx file and the timestamp will be enough to force an update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198306/discussion-between-psionman-and-davidw).